# Ordering map based on property in list of object

Tags: c#, linq

Run into an issue with LINQ atm.
I currently have a class that can have two names - MeterName and ChannelName; both strings. However, the ChannelName property may be empty or null.
This class is called ChannelRecord, which contains a few other properties related to the Meter + Channel name.

These are stored in a List, which is mapped to a DateTime in a dictionary. This means we have this:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, List<ChannelRecord>> outputMap = ....;
```

I am trying to sort the channel records based on their meter & channel name, with meters starting with numbers and symbols coming first, and z coming last.

So far my code looks like this:

```
var orderedMap = outputMap.Select(x => x.Value) // as in KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>
        .OrderBy(list => list.Select(record => record.MeterName))
        .ThenBy(list => list.Select(record => record.ChannelName));
```

However, I get the exception that "one of the objects must implement IComparable". Which is funny, because AFAIK, strings implement IComparable. I know KeyValuePair doesn't, but I am `.Select()`ing a value from it.

What do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `list => list.Select(record => record.MeterName)` inside `OrderBy` returns `IEnumerable<string>`, which is not `IComparable`.

If you would like to re-order the lists *inside* the dictionary, but keep the dictionary itself as is (i.e. date keys would remain in place), you can do it like this:

```
var orderedMap = outputMap
    .ToDictionary(
        x => x.Key
    ,   x => x.Value
           .OrderBy(element => element.MeterName)
           .ThenBy(element => element.ChannelName)
           .ToList()
    );
```

Comment: This is the solution I went with, but it's `.OrderBy(element => element.MeterName)` - no need for the nested select.

Comment: @DanPantry You're right, I copy-pasted your code, which expected lists. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

In this part:

```
.OrderBy(list => list.Select(record => record.MeterName))
```

the result of the lambda is an IEnumerable of strings, not a single string. The IEnumerable might only contain a single string, but there is now way for the compiler to know that.

Try this:

```
var orderedMap = outputMap.Select(x => x.Value) // as in KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>
    .OrderBy(list => list.Select(record => record.MeterName).First())
    .ThenBy(list => list.Select(record => record.ChannelName).First());
```

Comment: Surely this would be `list.Select(record => record.MeterName).First()`?

Comment: @DanPantry you are correct. The other way it would return records, which (presumably) still aren't IComparable.

Comment: Not only that, but `.First()` requires a predicate that returns bool

Comment: @DanPantry there is another overload of `First()` accepting no argument.

Comment: @KingKing True, but @Rik initially specified an example with `.First(record => record.MeterName)` :)

Comment: @DanPantry I didn't see that version :)

Comment: Yeah I sort of rolled the predicates for `select` and `first` into one, my bad.